# How via method I can change the attribute name?

Tags: ruby

I have a method defined as follow:

```
def foobar(arg)
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, arg: nil)
end
```

When i call `foobar('email')` or `foobar('name')` i want my method to return this
`FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: nil)` or `FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: nil)` respectively

How can i do it?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def foobar(parameter)
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, parameter.to_sym => nil)
end
```

Comment: thank you!so simple, I'm somewhere in an hour trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use *interpolation* too.

```
def foobar(arg)
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, :"#{arg}" => nil)
end
```